# How can I identify if item is uncheck in ListView

Tags: c#, uwp

On my ListView, IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled is enabled, but I want to know how to identify if an checked item is uncheck, is it on SelectionChanged, if yes, how?

here is an example image:
[image]

Thanks,
NicoTing

Comment: @Jessica I think it's explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it from the SelectionChangedEventArgs parameter.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.AddedItems.ToList();
        var item1 = e.RemovedItems.ToList();
    }
```

In this e.AddedItems will will return the checked items and e.RemovedItems will return the unchecked items.

Answer (score 0):

> I have try this

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   for (int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    if (listView2.Items[i].Checked == fail)
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question , I attached an image , can you please see

Answer (score -1):

Create a new column in the listview that contains "Checked" and "Unchecked". In your submit event, you can compare it to know it was unchecked or checked.

for the new record you will know if the new column field value is empty.

Comment: I think other way is you should use selection changed.

Comment: @lindexi , how is that on SelectionChanged event? can you please provide code?

Comment: What if the data in the list is from a database?